# Android compiler warning and app crashing

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting the following warning messages when I build my project in Eclipse.

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion  in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Invalid attribute name: 
Install        : mylib.so => libs/armeabi/mylib.so
    package
Invalid attribute name: 
    package
```

I do not have an Application.mk, but in my Android_Manifest.xml my minsdk is as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

I'm using android-ndk-r8e on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. When I suppress the warnings and run it on my phone, it crashes after a few seconds with the following relevant logcat trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(12089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12089): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: my.app.AccessSD.ListDevice:([B)J
```

Seems like the native library isn't being built properly? How can I solve this?

Comment: why don't you change your `android:minSdkVersion`

Comment: That APP_PLATFORM warning should not cause your app to crash. And I suggest you to share your Android.mk, the definition of the function that throws the error, and how you call it from Java.